# Adding LinuxFromScratch partition to Grub boot options

Tags: linux, grub

I have an Ubuntu 21.04 system that dualboots to Windows 10. `efibootmgr` reports:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001B,0000,0001,0017,0018,0019,001A,001C,001D,001E,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* Linux-Firmware-Updater
Boot0010  Setup
Boot0011  Boot Menu
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0016  MEBx Hot Key
Boot0017* USB CD
Boot0018* USB FDD
Boot0019* NVMe0
Boot001A* ATA HDD0
Boot001B* USB HDD
Boot001C* PCI LAN
Boot001D  Other CD
Boot001E  Other HDD
Boot001F* IDER BOOT CDROM
Boot0020* IDER BOOT Floppy
Boot0021* ATA HDD
Boot0022* ATAPI CD
```

I've been stepping through the Linux From Scratch build steps, which essentially have been creating a new partition, formatting it as ext4, mounting it as `/mnt/lfs` and then using that mount point with `chroot` to install system software. Grub 2.06 was compiled and installed at [this step](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.0-rc2/chapter08/grub.html).

I got to [this page](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.0-rc2/chapter10/grub.html) and it directed me to [this page](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/grub-setup.html). After mounting the EFI partition as `/boot/efi`:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p6 ext4       29G  4.9G   23G  18% /
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat      256M   38M  219M  15% /boot/efi
```

I got down to the line `grub-install --bootloader-id=LFS --recheck` but that failed saying it couldn't find a `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh`

I realised that grub is looking in the wrong `/usr/lib` directory and tried `grub-install --bootloader-id=LFS --recheck --directory=/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/nvme0n1p1` but that produces a message of:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `fat' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists
```

How do I add `/dev/nvme0n1p6` as an option in my multiboot?

Comment: You are specifying a partition. This is why it's failing. /dev/nvme0n1p1 is a partition. I do not see where in the LFS documentation it's saying to specify a paritition. Do not mix tutorials, it may cause your distro to become unbootable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your other OSs all boot using UEFI, you should have followed this note in the beginning of the GRUB installation chapter:

> Note
>
> If your system has UEFI support and you wish to boot LFS with UEFI, you can skip this package in LFS, and install GRUB with UEFI support (and its dependencies) following [the BLFS page](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/grub-efi.html) at the end of this chapter.

This will give you [slightly altered instructions for building GRUB](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/grub-efi.html) and [significantly different instructions for setting it up](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/grub-setup.html).

You tried to use the UEFI set-up instructions together with GRUB built for legacy BIOS. That's why it did not work.

Essentially, when building GRUB for UEFI, you'll need an extra font file and two more build-time configuration options: `--enable-grub-mkfont` and `--with-platform=efi`.

---

When a system already has Windows booting in UEFI style, that means the system disk must also be partitioned in GPT style... and that means there will be no unused space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition that would be needed for embedding the core image of the `i386-pc` version of GRUB. You would need to create an extra "biosboot" partition for it.

Also, having some operating systems boot in UEFI mode and others in legacy BIOS mode would mean you would most likely have to use the BIOS menus to switch between BIOS mode and UEFI mode: it would be impossible to choose between all the installed OSs in a single bootloader menu.

Some systems (usually laptops or name-brand pre-built desktops) also have reduced-functionality BIOS menus, and may not necessarily allow switching between different boot modes: on these systems, the system has a hardcoded preference for either legacy or UEFI style booting, and installing an OS of the preferred style can effectively make the other style unusable.

On both this Unix&Linux.SE and the SuperUser.SE, there are a lot of questions from users that have been trying to set up dual-boot, and have accidentally installed one OS to boot in legacy BIOS mode and another in UEFI mode, and don't like the results. Please don't make the same mistake as the writers of those questions.

Comment: Thankoyu - exactly right and a comprehensive answer. I stepped thru the grub EFI install and worked thru all the dependencies. efibootmgr now reports LFS as an option. I was wondering why BIOS seems to be the default patch for linux from scratch but it seems evident to me that that EFI introduces quite a few more steps